# GlanceAppWidget with clickable row: inner elements steal focus and clicks

Tags: android, glance-appwidget

I have a widget made with a android glance library.  There is a Row contains Image and Text. I need to make this row clickable.

```
 Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = GlanceModifier.fillMaxWidth().clickable(
            actionStartActivity(
                createOpenActivityIntent(
                   context = LocalContext.current
                )
            )
        )
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = GlanceModifier.padding(end = 8.dp),
            provider = ImageProvider(R.drawable.ic_open),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Text(
            text = LocalContext.current.getString(
                R.string.open
            )
        )
    }
```

The problem is that the row reacts to click only when I click on its area around of the Text and  Image. If I click the Image or Text, nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug in Glance `1.0.0-alpha04`. You can downgrade to `1.0.0-alpha03` for now, and it should hopefully be fixed in the next release

**Update:**
[Here's a link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242309357) to my post on the issue tracker, but there are a few others. And't it currently marked as "fixed", so it'll hopefully be working again in `1.0.0-alpha06`

Comment: Hey, do you have any ticket reference on this on the Google issues? I couldn't find anything so I'm not sure if this is going to be addressed on the Google developers side...

Comment: I updated the OP with the link