# Why doesn't the clickable modifier work for a Glance Widget?

Tags: android, glance

I have a very simple widget that I'm making with Glance, something like this:

```
 class MyWidget : GlanceAppWidget() {

    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {
        provideContent {
            WidgetContent(GlanceModifier.fillMaxSize(), context)
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun WidgetContent(modifier: GlanceModifier = GlanceModifier, context: Context) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier.background(R.color.white).clickable {
                actionStartActivity<MainActivity>()
            },
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(
                text = context.getString(R.string.foo),
                modifier = GlanceModifier.padding(12.dp)
            )
            Button(
                text = "Foo",
                onClick = actionStartActivity<MainActivity>()
            )
        }
    }
```

in this example, tapping on Button will launch my activity, however, the `clickable` modifier doesn't. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471947/jetpack-glance-widget-only-the-whitespace-is-clickable-text-and-image-are-not) and this is potentially a duplicate, unless there's a reason for that behaviour ? Perhaps it's impossible to do this for a specific reason ? I don't want to add a button here, I want the entire widget to respond to a click/tap, how can I do that ?

Glance version:

```
implementation("androidx.glance:glance-appwidget:1.0.0")
implementation("androidx.glance:glance-material3:1.0.0")
```

Adding the `.clickable` block to only the Text doesn't solve the problem either, perhaps `.clickable` just doesn't work with Glance yet?

Comment: What version of Glance are you using? [This issue comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) suggests that it was fixed in `1.0.0-beta01`.

Comment: hmm that might be worth a try, i think i'm on the wrong version

Comment: @CommonsWare updated my question to include the version, not sure if this is the "right" version to be using or not, thank you

Comment: In theory, that should contain the fix. You might poke through the issue tracker to see if there are any other open tickets. If there are none, and you can create a project that reproduces the issue, consider opening your own ticket.

Comment: thanks. I've tried a few things and I feel like this example is simple enough to the point that I can't be making a mistake, but nothing I've tried seems to work unfortunately. the `.clickable` modifier doesn't seem to be working

Comment: The reason why I suggest a sample project in the issue tracker is that it makes it easier for Google to reliably reproduce your results. If you just give them a Kotlin function and nothing else, your ticket may be less likely to be worked on.

Comment: i have a feeling the answer is going to be ` don't launch activities from something that isn't a button` and hopefully that isn't the case, as i don't find it unrealisitic to open the app when you tap on the widget, but let's see

Comment: `RemoteViews` are not very flexible, and all Glance is doing is giving you an interesting API to create and update `RemoteViews`. I *think* there is a way to do what you want with `RemoteViews` though.

Comment: @CommonsWare found a solution to this, not sure if this should just be deleted as it could be considered just a mistake on my side. will leave it here for the community to decide i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

actionStartActivity is an action type, as such it can only be passed to modifiers, it can't be invoked as a lambda function.

instead of:

```
.clickable {
   actionStartActivity<MainActivity>()
},
```

it should be:

```
.clickable(actionStartActivity<MainActivity>())
```

Comment: I am surprised you did not get a compile error. Did you have an imported `clickable()` extension function that supported the first syntax?

Comment: no compilation error and the import `import androidx.glance.action.clickable` supports both of these options

Comment: OK, *that* feels like a bug, if it clams to support both but only one works.

Comment: well, to be honest i'm not sure how i should have known only one would work here, but at least there's a solution to the problem

Comment: I played with this and understand better now. `clickable { }` needs to do something directly (e.g., mutate some state that triggers recomposition). `clickable(ActionCallback)` executes the action. The equivalent of of `clickable(ActionCallback)` with a lambda is probably something like `clickable { callback.onAction() }` (with appropriate parameters to `onAction()`). If all you do in the lambda is *instantiate` the action, nothing will ever call `onAction()`, and so nothing happens. This might be helped by a good Lint rule, or if the lambda *evaluates* to an `ActionCallback` to use it.

Comment: thank you. well, i'm glad you at least verified my Q&A here, hopefully this will be useful to others in future if they decide to use Glance

Comment: i'm also willing to delete this post, or people can vote to close it as a mistake on my side, should they wish to do that. however i do feel like there's some value here, as this wasn't entirely obvious to me at least

Comment: Oh, definitely keep the post! I was just trying to provide a bit more depth as to why we got into this mess in the first place!